# Hay alguna forma de obtener solo los numeros sin repetir de una lista en python?

Tags: python

Tengo estos datos, y estaba pensando en crear un loop para que me diga cuantas veces se repiten los números, pero tendría que hacerlo con cada uno ¿hay algún comando que me facilite solo contar los numero que no se repitan?

`datos = [3,2,0,3,0,3,0,2,0,0,3,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,2,3,0,1,0,4,1,0,2,1,3,1,1,2,1,2,0,2,4,0]`

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido a Stack Overflow Draor c:

Encontré la forma de hacer lo que buscas. Se pueden convertir la lista en un set para obtener los números presentes en la lista sin que se repitan.
Luego, usando compresión de listas, podemos crear un diccionario cuyas claves sean el numero y el valor la cantidad de veces que aparece en la lista.

```
datos = [3,2,0,3,0,3,0,2,0,0,3,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,2,3,0,1,0,4,1,0,2,1,3,1,1,2,1,2,0,2,4,0]
cant_numeros = {num:datos.count(num) for num in set(datos)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución simple:

```
datos = [3,2,0,3,0,3,0,2,0,0,3,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,2,3,0,1,0,4,1,0,2,1,3,1,1,2,1,2,0,2,4,0]
totales = {}
for valor in datos:
    if valor not in totales:
        totales[valor] = 1
    else:
        totales[valor] += 1
print(totales)
print("Items que aparecen solo una vez")
for x, v in totales.items():
    if v == 1:
        print(x)
print("---")
```

Con el `for` recorremos los datos uno a uno.

Tenemos un diccionario `totales` indexado por número (el mismo que viene de `datos`). El valor asociado es el número de veces que está presente en `datos`.

Finalmente, recorremos el diccionario en busca de aquellas entradas con valor == 1 e imprimimos la llave, que es el número que no se repite (no hay ninguno).

Produce:

```
{3: 6, 2: 7, 0: 13, 1: 10, 4: 2}
Items que aparecen solo una vez
---
```

que nos dice que el número 3 aparece 6 veces; el número 2, 7 veces, etc.

Todos los valores se repiten.